# Cleaning/Compacting multiple states represented by boolean variables

Tags: c#, wpf, boolean, state, code-cleanup

In an implementation, i have a lot of states, represented by boolean variables, in such a way that when a state is true, variable against that state is true, and many or all of the others are false. It is not a good way, and since i was only planning my solution before coding, it turned out to be like this. Now i have to clean it. What is the best possible solution to clean?

I was thinking about enum, give a name to each state, and this way one variable can contain the state name instead of multiple variables. But the problem is that there is other information associated with some states, such as one or two instances of Point or int variables, which are only for that state. How to accommodate them if enum is used?

What is the most elegant and appropriate solution in situations like these?

Comment: Your question is too manifold and only relevant to an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet (namely your application). Try to break your problem down into separate questions whose answers are likely to help other users as well.

Comment: Fixed, all my application specific problems removed, and only one general question left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the state design pattern to implement state machines, instead of mapping states to an enum, each state is a class, events are member functions of the state classes.